# Prove that $c^3f(c)+c f(c)\ge1$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Let $f:[0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ a continuous function that satisfies $\int_0^1 2 x f(x) dx >\pi/2$. I need to prove there is
$c\in(0,1)$ such that $c^3f(c)+c f(c)\ge1$.
My guess is the mean value theorem. Am I on the right track?

Comment: Are you sure there's no typo here? Since $f$ is continuous, the function $x^3f(x)+xf(x)$ is obviously $0$ at $x=0$ and so takes on values $<1$ for all $x\in [0,a)$ for some positive $a$.

Comment: I solved a modified version of it but this seem harder.

Comment: @Chris'ssisterandpals thank you.

Comment: @TedShifrin there was a typo.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since
$$\int_0^1\big(xf(x)-\frac{1}{1+x^2}\big)dx=\int_0^1xf(x)dx-\frac{\pi}{4}>0,$$
there exists $c\in(0,1)$, such that $cf(c)-\frac{1}{1+c^2}>0$. The conclusion follows.

**Remark:** It suffices to assume that $f$ is (Riemann or Lebesgue) integrable on $[0,1]$. Continuity is not necessary.

Comment: Very helpful. Thank you.

Comment: @Jimmy_Jp: You are welcome. Just in case that you are new to this website, you may choose to [accept](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/3287/46120) an answer to your question if you wish.

Comment: @Jimmy_Jp: Thank you for your appreciation!

Comment: @Landspace these questions are always over my head.

Comment: @Jimmy_Jp: Please don't be discouraged by those questions. Many questions will become easier to be handled once you get more experienced. Some other questions may be so tricky or artificial that it doesn't matter if we cannot solve them.

Comment: @Jimmy_Jp you're nice. The experience is the key :-)